# How to fetch remote ref retrieved via ListReferences

Tags: libgit2sharp

I am trying to achieve this:

1) if branch name contains pr/, I use this code to find the reference:

```
var remoteReferences = repository.Network.ListReferences(repositoryUrl);
foreach (var remoteRef in remoteReferences)
{
    if (string.Equals(remoteRef.CanonicalName, targetBranchName))
    {
        return remoteRef;
    }
}
```

2) Then I try to make it the head:

```
repository.Refs.UpdateTarget(repository.Refs.Head, newHead);
```

However, it doesn't work:

> Additional information: Reference 'refs/pull/30/head' not found

I tried manually adding the remote ref to the repository.Refs list, but that doesn't seem to work.

How can I get the current head to point to the remote ref?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ListReferences` gives you a list of references as they appear in the remote repository. They are not downloaded or inserted into your local namespaces.

`UpdateTarget()` (like 99% of Git operations) work on local references with their names as they appear locally. You do not have a `refs/pull/30/head` reference locally and thus cannot switch to that branch.

That said, you wouldn't (shouldn't) be able to perform that `UpdateTarget()` even if you did have such a reference, as that is not a branch and thus cannot switch branches to it.

In order to download that reference, you need to perform a fetch, possibly specifying a local name by which to know that reference. It is common to store these PR references under the namespace of the remote they belong to, but as you do not have a remote configured but a url, you might like to store that reference in `FETCH_HEAD` by leaving the target empty or specify some scratch namespace like so

```
repository.Network.Fetch(repositoryUrl, new[] {
    "refs/pull/30/head:refs/heads/scratch/30/head"
});
repository.Refs.UpdateTarget("HEAD", "refs/heads/scratch/30/head");
```